# folders in sidebar

Tags: directory, taskbar

I guess this is another noob question. I would like to add my documents folder to side bar. There are quite a few proposals how to do it (and not sure, why it is not permit by default).
Is this still a relevant way to do it on 22.04 LTS?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Doing what you want to do only saves you ONE click, why bother? Granted, with Unity it was possible by right-clicking Nautilus (now Files) and the menu had direct access to any of your personal folders, Since the reintroduction of Gnome we lost that option.

Comment: With "side bar", you mean the Dock, where you can click icons to launch applications?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the file manager you are using. I guess most of them would do this if you drag and drop any folder to the spot you want. It works with Dolphine (default file manager in Kubuntu) and Nautilus (default file manager in Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

In the standard Ubuntu desktop, based on Gnome Shell, there is no easy way. The suggested workflow for this user case is to launch the file manager, then use the "Bookmarks" feature for quick access to folders.

Your "Documents" folder is an easy case. Open your file manager, and you will immediately see "Documents" as one of your top level folders in your home directory.

Still, it is possible to add a launcher that directly opens a specific folder. Only the graphical tools are not provided. You can install "Alacarte" or "Menulibre". These allow to create launchers, which you then can pin on the dock. As command, you can use `xdg-open Documents`. This will open the "Documents" folder in whatever your default file manager is.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag'n'drop the folder to the sidebar. You'll notice that, while dragging, a      `New bookmark` item appears in the Sidebar. Drag the folder over it and release; DONE! :)

The bookmarks will appear under the *"Shares"* section.
Unfortunately I didn't find a way to add custom folders to the main default-folders list (on top of the sidebar), like I was used to do on macOS.
However, hopefully this will suffice for your needs.

Comment: I think the OP was asking about putting a shortcut to their documents folder in the dock, not the bookmarks section of nautilus. In other words, they want the shortcut to be clickable even when nautilus is not open.

Comment: Re-reading it, you might be correct. It's not clear what the "side bar" should be related to (as I, as you mention, call "Dock" the desktop sidebar). I came looking for the answer regarding the file manager, so my interpretation was biased; if the answer gets clearer I'll remove my answer.